# What does I18N safe mean?

Tags: internationalization, terminology

I came across a comment in some code referring to said code being "I18N safe".

What does this refer to?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I + (some 18 characters) + N = InternationalizatioN

I18N safe means that steps were taken during design and development that will facilitate Localization (L10N) at a later point.

Comment: Interestingly, the term I18N is I18N-safe, because it avoids the s/z UK/US thing.

Answer (score 14):

This is most often referred to a code or construct ready for I18N - i.e easily supported by common I18N techniques. For instance, the following is ready:

```
printf(loadResourceString("Result is %s"), result);
```

while the following is not:

```
printf("Result is " + result);
```

because the word order may vary in different languages. Unicode support, international date-time formatting and the like also qualify.

**EDIT:** added loadResourceString to make an example close to real life.

Comment: why isn't that second one the same as the first one?  Doesn't result just get pasted in in place of %s?

Comment: It does BUT the second one allows you to move the string to resources easily and rearrange words. You can then translate it as for instance "%s является результатом" (in russian) - notice different word order, you cannot use the first form directly.

Comment: Great answer. This is EXACTLY what i18n-safe means. It usually refers to functions like this one.

Comment: Wouldn't be then "printf( fromResource , result ); " instead?

Comment: @Oscar: this form is not 'I18N safe', it is one step further when a particular I18N technique is already applied. I think 'I18N safe' refers to general ideas making code more suitable for I18N. However your example qualify as well.

Comment: I'm with Oscar on this. Neither of your examples are I18N safe - both need modification. The second one is a step on the way, but you're not world-ready yet.

Comment: A small point: this answer doesn't actually tell you *what* "I18N" is, just provides an example of some code that is versus some code that isn't.

Comment: I have a doubt: would using "%S" instead of "%s" make it more i18n-safe, or it's ok to use "%s" and then make %S-changes all over the code? Just curious to know what do you guys think.

Answer (score 10):

i18n means i**nternationalizatio**n => i (**18 letters**) n. Code that's marked as i18n safe would be code that correctly handles non-ASCII character data (e.g. Unicode).

Comment: And, frequently, code that keeps strings in a separate file that can be swapped out, rather than in the source code.

Answer (score 7):

Internationalization.  The derivation of it is "the letter I, eighteen letters, the letter N".

Answer (score 5):

I18N stands for Internationalization.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

its a numeronym for Internationalization.

Different from Acronym, numeronym is a number based word (eg 411 = information, k9 = canine);

In code, this will normally be a folder title, that It generally refers to code that will work in international environments - with different locale, keyboard, character sets etc. ... "

Read more about it here: http://www.i18nguy.com/origini18n.html

Comment: very interesting

Answer (score 3):

i18n is a shorthand for "internationalization". This was coined at DEC and actually uses lowercase *i* and *n*.

As a sidenote: L10n stands for "localization" and uses capital *L* to distinguish it from the lowercase *i*.

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional information, I would guess that it means the code handles text as UTF8 and is locale-aware.  See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I18N) for more information.

Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: As I'm in a pedantic mood - it could handle the text as any Unicode not just UTF8. UTF7 or UTF16 would do just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I18N stands for [Internationalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I18N).

In a nutshell: I18N safe code means that it uses some kind of a lookup table for texts on the UI. For this you have to support non-ASCII encodings. This might seem to be easy, but there are some [gotchas](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001075.html).

Answer (score 1):

i18n-safe is a vague concept.  It generally refers to code that will work in international environments - with different locale, keyboard, character sets etc.  True i18n-safe code is hard to write.

It means that code cannot rely on:

> sizeof (char) == 1

because that character could be a UTF-32 4-byte character, or a UTF-16 2-byte character, and occupy multiple bytes.

It means that code cannot rely on the length of a string equalling the number of bytes in a string.  It means that code cannot rely on zero bytes in a string indicating a nul terminator.  It means that code cannot simply assume ASCII encoding of text files, strings, and inputs.

Answer (score 1):

"I18N safe" coding means the code that doesn't introduce I18N bugs. I18N is a numeronym for Internationalization, where there are 18 characters between I and N.

There are multiple categories of issues related to i18n such as:
Culture Format: Date Time formats(DD/MM/YY in UK and MM/DD/YY in US ), number formats, Timezone, Measuring units change from culture to culture. The data must be accepted, processed and displayed in the right format for the right culture/locale.
International Characters Support: All the characters from all the different languages should be accepted, processed and displayed correctly. 
Localizability: The translatable strings should not be hard code. They should be externalized in resource files.

"I18N Safe" coding means that none of the above issue is introduced by the way the code is written.

Answer (score 0):

i18n deals with 
- moving hard coded strings  out of the code (not all should be by the way) so they can be localized/translated (localization == L10n), as others have pointed out, and also deals with
- locale sensitive method, such as 
--methods dealing with text handling (how many words in a Japanese text is far obvious:), order/collation in different languages/writing systems, 
--dealing with date/time (the simplest example is showing am/pm for the US, 24 h clocks for France for instance, going to more complex calendars for specific countries), 
--dealing with arabic or hebrew (orientation of UI, of text, etc.), 
--encoding as others have pointed out
--database issues
it's a fairly comprehensive angle. Just dealing with "String externalization" is far from enough.

Some (software) languages are better than others in helping developers write i18n code (meaning code which will run on different locales), but it remains a software engineering responsibility.